# Please explain gettersetter_method from this method

Tags: java, getter-setter

I have one small program related to getter and setter concept, I'm getting null value for a reason I don't understand. Here is my code, where I need to pass multiple strings in single object:

```
public class simple {

    public Object getmethod(){
        getter s=new getter();
        String app="apple";
        s.setApp(app);      
        String ble="blue";
        s.setGrp(ble);
        String re="grape";
        s.setGrp(re);           
        return s;
    }
}
```

Here is the getter method:

```
public class getter {
    String app;
    String org;
    String  grp;
    String mn;

    public String getApp() {
        return app;
    }

    public void setApp(String app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    public String getOrg() {
        return org;
    }

    public void setOrg(String org) {
        this.org = org;
    }

    public String getGrp() {
        return grp;
    }

    public void setGrp(String grp) {
        this.grp = grp;
    }
}
```

And here is the test class:

```
public class Check {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        simple s=new simple();
        getter g=new getter();
        s.getmethod();
        String first=g.getApp();
        String second=  g.getGrp();
        String third=g.getOrg();
        System.out.println("the value 1st is " + first + "the second" + 
                              second +"3rd is"+third);
    }    
}
```

This is where I am getting null as the value.

Answer (score 0):

You got to check [java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for class, method and variable name,

The problem is with your code in main method, you are not using the reference returned by getmethod(). instead you are instantiating another instance of getter.

```
public class Check {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        simple s=new simple(); 
        // you may avoid cast to getter by changing return type of 
        // method getmethod() from Object to getter. 
        getter g=(getter)s.getmethod(); // cast is necessary 
        String first=g.getApp();
        String second=  g.getGrp();
        String third=g.getOrg();
       System.out.println("the value 1st is " + first + "the second" + second +"3rd is"+third);
    }    
}
```

As per [java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) please name your Classes as below:

- getter -> Getter
- simple -> Simple
- Your getter and setter method and your variable are named as per the convention.

Comment: awesome buddy... its perfectly working,surely  i ill change the name of the class(thanx for indicating naming convention).. thanx for great response...

Comment: if this answer your question please accept it as an answer by clicking the check mark next on the left side of this answer.

Comment: I did that ,but it showing that you need 15 reputation is required to publish it..how to get that reputation?? I have only 8.

Comment: you will earn it :) by answering question or asking interesting question. I just gave you up vote, that bring you to 13. you need some more ... check back here when you have enough - cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> here i am getting null as the value

You are printing the `new getter` variables, which have not been set, and so they are all null.

On its own, `s.getmethod()` will call the method, and create a new getter (different than the one you made earlier), but return to nothing, so you need an assignment.

```
getter g=(getter)s.getmethod();
```

If you don't want the cast, change the method to return a getter instead of Object

```
public getter getmethod(){
```

So you can do

```
getter g=s.getmethod();
```

Comment: I did that ,but it showing that you need 15 reputation is required to publish it..how to get that reputation?? I have only 8.

Comment: As far as I know, that's for upvoting with the arrows. You can always accept questions that you ask